# Print an image tiled on a web page

Tags: html, css, browser, printing

I need to be able to tile an image across a region, but also have that pattern print.

Traditionally, you tile images using a repeated background, but backgrounds don't print in most browsers unless you explicitly turn on that behavior.

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjD3X/) for an example of what I need (except this example won't print correctly).

Any dirty tricks are perfectly allowable as long as the crosshatch pattern will print.

*Relevant bits of the jsFiddle excerpted below:*

```
<style>
#danger div { background: white; padding:15px; margin:15px;  }
#danger { margin:15px;border: 1px solid black;
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTOTJ.png);
}
</style>
<div id="danger"><div>
    <h3>Danger Will Robinson</h3>
    <p>Don't forget to frob the sporkle.
</div></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand it. Could you give me an example?

Comment: You *have* an example, right there. Click the jsFiddle for one that you can view. But note that if you print it, the crosshatch pattern won't print.

Comment: Ok, now I understand ^^ I think there isn't a way to do this, sorry. Have you considered to use a print stylesheet?

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía Yes, but putting it on a print stylesheet doesn't make it print.

Comment: What I would do is make the image larger than what you need (tile it yourself in photoshop), then put the image in the html (instead of background), in a div with position absolute, with a low z-index to keep it behind the text. The trick there will be to make the div as tall as you need.

Comment: Ask on this StackExchange printing site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46690/printing

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a cross-browser way to do this and the best option would be to make a print stylesheet (with a different style) or put the background in the HTML file. If you want to force Chrome and Safari to print css bacgrounds you can use `-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;` in each element that you want to print.

Try this one http://jsfiddle.net/xjD3X/1/

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment above, I made this: http://jsfiddle.net/xjD3X/2/ It uses position absolute to place the image behind your text, and since it's in the html, it prints:

```
#bg {display:block; position:absolute; top:0; left: 0; z-index: 0;}
#danger div { background: white; padding:15px; margin:15px; position:relative; z-index: 100; }
```

The only issue is that it won't tile by itself. But if your image is like the one you used in your Jsfiddle, a larger version of it won't be too heavy.

I used a span for the image, but you can use a div, or any other tag.